# Ошибка в выходе за пределы списка

Tags: python

Есть двумерный масив, который формируется с помощью считывания данных из текстового файла.
Необходимо пройтись по нему проверяя первые элементы каждой строчки. Реализовано это следующим способом:

```
for i in range(len(spic)):
    if spic[i][0] == '0':
        print(spic[i])
        #тут функция
    elif spic[i][0] == '1':
        print(spic[i])
        #тут функция
    elif spic[i][0] == '2':
        print(spic[i])
        #тут функция
    elif spic[i][0] == '3':
        print(spic[i])
        #тут функция
    elif spic[i][0] == '4':
        print(spic[i])
        тут функция
    elif spic[i][0] == '5':
        print(spic[i])
        #тут функция
    elif spic[i][0] == '6':
        print(spic[i])
        #тут функция
    elif spic[i][0] == '7':
        print(spic[i])
        #тут функция
    elif spic[i][0] == '8':
        print(spic[i])
        #тут функция
    elif spic[i][0] == '9':
        print(spic[i])
        #тут функция
    elif spic[i][0] == '10':
        print(spic[i])
        #тут функция
```

Но на первом элементе высвечивается ошибка выхода за пределы массива:

```
  File "D:\video\test_program.py", line 140, in <module>
      if spic[i][0] == '0':
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

Программа для формирования двухмерного массива:

```
file1 = open("test.txt", "r")
spic = []

while True:
    # считываем строку
    line = file1.readline()
    time_line = line.split()
    if len(time_line) != 0:
        spic.append(time_line)
    # прерываем цикл, если строка пустая
    if not line:
        break
# выводим строку
#print(line.strip())

# закрываем файл
file1.close
```

В чем может быть проблема? Фай не пустой.

Comment: На пустые строки проверили?

Comment: попробуйте `print(spic)`? Ведь, если сразу просто посмотреть на содержимое того, по чему итерируешься или к чему по индексу доступаешься, то все должно стать понятно. Либо отладчиком очень полезно будет научиться пользоваться, так даже правильнее будет.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in spic:
    if i:
        print(i[0])
        ... #тут ваши переборы и функции
    else:
        print('Пустая строка!')
```

Так точно на ошибку не наткнетесь. К тому же `if len(time_line) != 0:` лучше заменить на `if len(time_line):`, а функции занести в словарь ключами которого будут цифры (чтобы не городить миллион `if`)